# Case insensitive match in SPARQL triple

Tags: sparql

Is there a way to make the following query case insensitive?

```
ASK {
    VALUES (?r) { (dbr:Game_of_Thrones) }
        { ?r ?p ?o }
        UNION
        { ?s ?r ?o }
        UNION
        { ?s ?p ?r }
    }
```

It shall return true no matter if I use `dbr:Game_of_Thrones` or `dbr:game_of_thrones`.

I tried using `LCASE()` but it's not allowed inside the triples. Is there another way?
I'm using the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint (https://dbpedia.org/sparql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRIs are case-sensitive for good reasons. If you really want to workaround this then you have to use `FILTER(lcase(str(?tmp)) = lcase(str(?r)))` in each `UNION` clause:

```
ASK {
    VALUES (?r) { (dbr:Game_of_Thrones) }
        { ?tmp ?p ?o. FILTER(LCASE(STR(tmp)) = LCASE(STR(?r))) }
        UNION
        { ?s ?r ?o. FILTER(LCASE(STR(tmp)) = LCASE(STR(?r))) }
        UNION
        { ?s ?p ?r. FILTER(LCASE(STR(tmp)) = LCASE(STR(?r))) }
    }
```

Note, this can result in poor performance at it has to scan over all triples and do String comparison.

For fuzzy search, you should really think about a full-text index.

I'd also suggest omitting the second `UNION` clause as long as you're looking for resources that are probably not schema entities, thus, never occur in predicate position of an RDF triple.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think you're right that just ignoring the case and doing string comparisons isn't the proper way to go for my use case.

Comment: What is your use-case? Maybe we can think about a more efficient solution then?

Comment: I want to check whether a combination of words (e.g. `game of thrones`) belongs to a DBpedia resource. I think a quick way to do this would be using the DBpedia Lookup API like this: http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search/PrefixSearch?QueryClass=&MaxHits=5&QueryString=game%20of%20thrones

Comment: Hm, in general, I'd pref to search in labels of resources, but it depends on the input of your application. Something like `select distinct ?s {        
?s ?p ?o. 
?s rdfs:label ?l. 
filter(langmatches(lang(?l), 'en'))
?l bif:contains "'game of thrones'"
}` is a common query and uses the Virtusos fulltext index of literals.